# find user2 friends + mutual count with user1

Tags: php, mysql

mysql to find user2 Friends and get mutual_count with user1 ( with every user2 friend)

Table users

```
user_id |   username
------------------
1       |   user1
2       |   user2
3       |   user3
4       |   user4
5       |   user5
```

table friends

```
user_one_id |   user_two_id
------------------------
1           |   2
1           |   4
2           |   3
2           |   4
3           |   1
5           |   2
```

Expected output           //( user2 friends : check result user_id with `user1 to get mutual count)`

```
user_id | mutual_count
------------------------
1       |   2             // user1 and user1 mutual `users(user2,user3,user4)`
3       |   1             // user3 and user1 mutual users(user2)
4       |   1             // user4 and user1 mutual users(user2)
5       |   0             // user5 and user1 -> No mutual users
```

mysql statement

```
SELECT  users.user_id,

    (SELECT count(a.friendID) FROM
        (   SELECT user_two_id friendID FROM friends  WHERE user_one_id = users.user_id
            UNION 
            SELECT user_one_id friendID FROM friends WHERE user_two_id = users.user_id
        ) AS a 
        JOIN  
        (   SELECT user_two_id friendID FROM friends WHERE user_one_id = 1
            UNION 
            SELECT user_one_id friendID FROM friends WHERE user_two_id = 1
        ) AS b 
        ON  a.friendID = b.friendID
    ) as mutual_count

FROM friends LEFT JOIN  users    
ON friends.user_one_id = users.user_id or  friends.user_two_id = users.user_id  
WHERE (friends.user_one_id = 2 OR friends.user_two_id = 2)   AND users.user_id != 2
```

Error I get
Unknown column 'users.user_id' in 'where clause'
problem subquery to get mutual_count canot know users.user_id

any help appreciated

Comment: I finding user2 Friends then why user2 apear in result?

Comment: and get mutual count of result friends with user1

Answer (score 0):

Your hunch to use a union between the friends table was on the right track.  The issue here is that a relationship between friends is only recorded in one direction, but we really need to detect each relationship regardless of direction.  The `UNION` trick allows each relationship to be counted properly.

In the query below, the base table is this union.  We self join it, on the conditions that:

- The first table's `user_one_id` is 2
- The first table's `user_two_id` matches to the *second* table's `user_one_id`
- The second table's `user_two_id` is *not* 2, which would just be a cycle back to where we started

Then, we just aggregate by the first table's `user_two_id` and count the number of distinct friends to get the result.

```
SELECT
    t1.user_two_id AS user_id,
    COUNT(DISTINCT t2.user_two_id) AS mutual_count
FROM
(
    SELECT user_one_id, user_two_id
    FROM friends
    UNION ALL
    SELECT user_two_id, user_one_id
    FROM friends
) t1
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT user_one_id, user_two_id
    FROM friends
    UNION ALL
    SELECT user_two_id, user_one_id
    FROM friends
) t2
    ON t1.user_one_id = 2 AND
       t1.user_two_id = t2.user_one_id AND
       t2.user_two_id <> 2
WHERE
    t1.user_two_id <> 2
GROUP BY
    t1.user_two_id
ORDER BY
    t1.user_two_id;
```

### Demo

Comment: no - you get user2 Firends with all friends cout   , but I want to get this friends  mutual friends count with user1

Comment: @khalidseleem I fixed it.  I'm on a cell phone right now, thanks for your patience.

Comment: I know the result as I want , but I where I specify user1 #1   , I want to use 1 in the statemnt

Comment: @khalidseleem The user # is hard coded in three places in my query.  If you can't figure out how to change it to another user, then you should review basic SQL before proceeding.

Comment: I want to determine user 2 and user 1 in the statment and also want to join it with users table  as I want  fetch some fields from it

Comment: Then you may join my query to another table using the matching mutual friend IDs.  I have answered your original question.

Comment: can you make your query with determine  user 1 ,  My best Regards to you